# chart.Bar() in R cannot take a zoo object

Tags: r

On the help page of the function **chart.Bar**, a zoo object can be an argument.
However, on the console of RStudio, errors appeared.

```
> chart.Bar(lab4Returns.z, legend.loc="bottom", main="")
Error in legend(x = lc$x, y = lc$y, legend = legend.names, xjust = lc$xjust,  : 
unused argument (lend = "butt")
In addition: Warning message:
In plot.xts(x = y, y = NULL, ..., col = colorset, type = type, lty = lty,  :
only the univariate series will be plotted
```

I have checked the dimension of that zoo object. It shows that:

```
> dim(lab4Returns.z)
[1] 143   3
```

Here are first six elements of that zoo object:

```
> head(lab4Returns.z)
             VBLTX     FMAGX      SBUX
Feb 1998 -0.004881  0.073069  0.078858
Mar 1998  0.001037  0.049066  0.135702
Apr 1998  0.006181  0.011513  0.060219
May 1998  0.018136 -0.045728 -0.002601
Jun 1998  0.020749  0.067677  0.107312
Jul 1998 -0.005911 -0.007508 -0.243824
```

I have tried another function **chart.TimeSeries**. It can take a zoo object as an argument with no errors appeared. **chart.Bar** and **chart.TimeSeries** are similar functions from the **PerformanceAnalytics package**. Why things do not work for **chart.Bar** only?

```
> chart.TimeSeries(lab4Returns.z, legend.loc="bottom", main="")
```

How to make chart.Bar take a zoo object as an argument?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you just `as.data.frame()` the zoo object? Does that hurt it?

Comment: Which package does `chart.Bar` come from?

Comment: It comes from the PerformanceAnalytics package.

Comment: After applying as.data.frame(), all the elements of that zoo object appeared (which seems normal). But char.Bar() still cannot take the zoo object as an argument.